# Typescript Error, Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I was working with typeORM and typegraphql, and I was defining resolver.

I wanted to traverse object and change them all.

But I got this error below and don't know why.

userResolver.ts

```
// Change User Information
@Mutation(() => UserResponse)
async changeUserInfo(
    @Arg("info") info: UserInformationInput,
    @Ctx() {req}: MyContext
): Promise<UserResponse|undefined> {
....
....
/////////////////////////////
const testObject = {
    spp: "asdf",
    slsl: "asdssf",
}
console.log("Before testObject Iteration:", testObject)
let tkey: keyof typeof testObject;
for (tkey in testObject) {
    testObject[tkey] = "llll"; // No Error with test Object!
}
console.log("After testObject Iteration:", testObject);

console.log("Before info Iteration:", info);
let k: keyof typeof info;
for (k in info) {
    info[k] = "mamamama"; // <-- Error! 
                          // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
console.log("After info Iteration:", info);
/////////////////////////////
....
....
}
```

UserInformationInput.ts

```
import { Field, InputType } from "type-graphql";

@InputType()
export class UserInformationInput {
@Field()
userId: string;
@Field()
firstName: string;
@Field()
lastName: string;
@Field()
userName: string;
@Field()
age: number;
@Field()
email: string;
@Field()
password: string;
@Field()
sex: string;
@Field()
univ: string;
}
```

What is the difference between 'testObject' and 'info'?

And, how can I traverse and change values of 'info'?

Comment: When posting, be sure to reduce your problem down to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. There's a lot of extra baggage above. [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/mpD8bm) of what a [mcve] might look like for the above (

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `testObject`'s properties are all of type `string`, but `UserInformationInput` has properties that are strings and also a property (`age`) that isn't a string (specifically, it's a `number`). If you read a value from it, `info[k]` would have the type `string | number`, because in the general case `k` might refer to any property of `UserInformationInput`. Since that might refer to a property of type number, you can't assign a string to it. (You get the same error with `testObject` if you add a non-string property to it [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoEkQwPZQC2cYweIOADgK5jIDeAsAFDJvLWZRYAmAXMnRgooAOYBuFu2RxREASGqEARtEnMAviwTkhySEIDyygFYQEdALwMp7dJUoCARHHQ8YTgDS226ADb+zq486Oge3qzssvLIACwATBEa6iww1CAWZCD6EEIAFKD4AhjYuATEpORUtACUNpFsOiDoeH4QAHR+eKJ5TgBCEPhQKAZgxmYWyFiQUCRZfF45RqbmYDU+yG10YADWEACeAnv7eDD6+5QQp0tjKxbq0kPIebsHyKA346t1TA3Sn3cwABtV77AC6yGsTj8ML8TnEyAA9IjkAAeSwY5AAUSgUAIyAAFtAUCA8AB3fR4PAbLR-JotNqdbq9ACCMBmAImdGm0Dm5AWnk53xSdN0rQ6XR6-UGBBQhTwUxmfJAAveZRqD3YW2QOyOB2uYAuVzO8s1bCeeR2arV+B+G2kwDOLyN13lQJ2EIxUKEIhAoicdr+-3Ybo9kOQTmIUbgxHhSJRqIAtInsbiCABCZD24M53PB5HIAAqRuQAHIfWJS+90MhSXRXOhgKIQHBlG1KedLmWQBAAG7QUvtbNsWnSUfseniplStkc+WK3mVFWLeUali0oA).)

(The wording of the error message does surprise me, but then I'm only middling at TypeScript at the moment.)